# Javascript - Search for first string after Domain

Tags: javascript

I have bought a chat plugin and only want to show the plugin symbol on the following pages:

https://stackoverflow.com/**en**/hello.html

https://stackoverflow.com/**fr**/hello.html

But not show it on:

https://stackoverflow.com/de/hello.html

What I'v got so far is:
It works, but the problem is when I have a domain that contains en or fr somewhere else in the domain, the chatsymbol is also show. **So I need to check if the first string after the domain is en or fr.** 
Can anybody help?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
url = window.location.href;
if( url.match(/en|fr/) ) {
document.write('<script id="sb-php-init" src="supportboard/php/sb.php">')
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your regular expression to include `/en/` or `/fr/`.
This will require you escape the forward-slash, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
url = window.location.href;
if( url.match(/\/en\/|\/fr\//) ) {
document.write('<script id="sb-php-init" src="supportboard/php/sb.php">')
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you that helped :)

Answer (score 1):

**[window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)** has a lot of utility properties that you can use. Since you do not want domain, you can choose to use `pathname`. This will give you everything after domain. So for your example, pathname would return `/en/hello.html`

Now that you have the path, you just have to ignore first character and the look for first `/` and you have your first path, which in your case would be `en`.

```
window.location.pathname.substring(1).split('/')[0]
```

Now you can just create a list of regions you want to allow and check if current region exists in this

Answer (score 0):

```
if (location.pathname.split('/')[1]) {
// your logic here
}
```

You are able to split  the path name of the current URL into an array. For example: `stackoverflow.com/posts/48062042/edit` will be transformed into `["", "posts", "48062042", "edit"]`.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

**I can do that as follow:**

```
var arr = window.location.href.split('/');
var isEnOrFr = arr[3].startsWith('en') || arr[3].startsWith('fr')
```

As @RobbieMilejczak pointed out, this approach needs a additional code:

```
if (!String.prototype.startsWith) {
    String.prototype.startsWith = function(searchString, position) {
        position = position || 0;
        return this.indexOf(searchString, position) === position;
    };
}
```

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: if you use this method, it should be noted that startsWith is not supported in any versions of IE

Comment: If you ar using `/` as the splitting character `var isEnOrFr = arr[1].startsWith('en/') || arr[1].startsWith('fr/')` will always be `false` because you are not going to have `/` in any elements of `arr`.